# How to get robot velocity in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.

I have built a little vehicle robot which can be controlled using keyboard.
Now i am interested to get the robot velocity in order to close control loop on it.

The question is what is the best way to do that ?

Is there a special sensor that I can include in my robot URDF model ?

Or, should I try to get it directly from the **/gazebo/model_states** topic ?

***update :***

I tried to subscribing to **/gazebo/model_states** topic using the following code :

```
ros::Subscriber vehicle_velocity_sub_;

vehicle_velocity_sub_ = nh_.subscribe<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/gazebo/model_states/twist[2]", 1000, &Dany_Obstacle_Avoidance_Commander::twist_data_processor, this);
```

But i got the following error  :

**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::InvalidNameException'
what():  Character [[] at element [26] is not valid in Graph Resource Name [/gazebo/model_states/twist[2]].  Valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, / and _.
Aborted (core dumped)**

It seems that ROS does not understand the vector operator "[]" used with topics.

nevertheless if I try to use it in rostopic command :

**rostopic echo /gazebo/model_states/twist[2]**

from the terminal it works fine.

Does anyone know what I doing wrong ?

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51484/how-to-get-robot-velocity-in-gazebo/) by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 192 on 2013-01-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yousubscribe to a twist message, so /gazebo/model_states/twist is the topic name, you should then read the value you want from the geometry_msgs::Twist object you receive in the callback!

Best Georg

---

Originally posted by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) with karma: 328 on 2013-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1